# Two auto increment in PHPMYADMIN SQL

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have existing table. Imagine I have (id, account_id, lastname, firstname) and my id is the primary key(auto increment) of my table. And my question is, is it possible that will have two auto increment in one table?

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done out of the box. Why do you want to do this may I ask? Both columns would contain the same value.

Comment: I want to have automatic data even I did not put value in account_id. Imagine I insert data in lastname, firstname. Ofcourse the id will have automatic data cause it's my primary key(auto increment) but I want to have automatic data too in my account_id, what can I do with that. Thankyouu!